# Intellij not showing local library

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to add a local library to a Maven project. Adding the corresponding dependency to the pom file works successfully, and so the project runs correctly. However, I'm trying to debug this library, for which I need to see the class files, which are not shown in the "External Libraries" option.

[image]

What could I do to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by a "local library"? One from your local repository?

Comment: @JFabianMeier a library I made. Not a public one

Comment: Have you run "Reload" from Maven Tool Window?

Comment: @y.bedrov yep...

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example for investigation?

Comment: @y.bedrov I'm afraid not. Anyway it is not really a necessity. Thanks for your interest!